# select max() returns wrong column

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to select a row from a table which has a max(col). However the matching column is wrong. It returns the first row of the table itself instead of the corresponding column of the max() value.

```
select 
    article, max(totalsale) as maxsale
from
    (select 
        article, sum(sold) as totalsale
    from art6maanden
    group by article) as maxsale
```

;

So the sub query would return this:

```
productA | 12
....
productZ | 70
```

The complete query returns:
`productA | 70`

It should return
`productZ | 70` since 70 is the max value

I'm using MySQL

Comment: Why do you have  "artikel" in the subquery and "article" in the main query?

Comment: @Emmad Kareem I guess it is a typo?

Comment: What database system are you using? If SQL 2008+ you can use MAX() OVER () syntax without the need for group by

Comment: @EmmadKareem it was a typo when i translated it. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the above query will be complaint by MS SQL Server with the error message saying column 'maxsale.article' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

So, perhaps you can add a ORDER BY statement.

```
SELECT TOP 1 article, totalsale as maxsalevalue
FROM
(SELECT article, sum(sold) as totalsale
FROM art6maanden
GROUP BY article) as maxsale
ORDER BY totalsale DESC
```

**EDIT** Since ORDER BY is not allowed. I will suggest a solution with HAVING statement.

```
SELECT article, sum(sold) as totalsale
FROM art6maanden
GROUP BY article
HAVING sum(sold) = (
    SELECT MAX(totalsales) AS MaxSale
    FROM
    (SELECT article, sum(sold) as totalsale
    FROM art6maanden
    GROUP BY article) Ref
)
```

The query above is done by following 3 steps.

1. Find the total sales of earch article;
2. Find the maximum value of all the total sales;
3. From the table, find the record having same amount of total sales as the maximum value. Thus, if there are more than one record having the maximum, all of them should be listed out, instead of just one maximum record.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: this gives me the exact same result as the sub-query, the entire list.

Comment: Oops, careless mistake. I have edited my answer. In this updated query, what it does is first sorting the result and then picking the first record, which will always be the one having the maximum total sales.

Comment: It's not allowed to use the order by statement in the assignment

Comment: I have updated my answer to not use ORDER BY statement, but a HAVING statement instead.

Comment: Ref is just a name to the subquery: (SELECT article, sum(sold) as totalsale FROM art6maanden GROUP BY article). Sometimes some DBMS will complain if I don't give it a name. So I added it in my solution as well.

Answer (score -1):

Here in the below query you can use your sub query in the place of "TotalSalesPerItem".

```
DECLARE @MaxSale int; 
Set @MaxSale = (select MAX(TotalSale)from TotalSalesPerItem);
select Item from TotalSalesPerItem
where TotalSale = @MaxSale
```

It will show the Item with Max Sale.

Comment: Actually this solution is somewhat correct also in MS SQL Server. Why do we vote it down?

Comment: **Thankx ChunLin** , for your support.